# Help with 64-bit integers in scripts?

Tags: shell, shell-script, ksh

Maybe I'm overthinking this (although I don't think I am)....or maybe there's a neater way of solving my problem ?

I have a requirement that if a file is larger than 1GB, it gets split into smaller chunks for processing.

No problem so far, that can easily be achieved with dd.

The problem is what happens with files larger than 4GB ?

My thinking at the moment is to start along the following lines ...

```
# Determine if file needs to be split
determineSplit() {
    typeset FILE_SIZE=$(ls -l "${1}" | awk '{print $5}');
    typeset -F NUMBER_OF_GIGS=$(print "${FILE_SIZE}/${BK_ONEGIG}"|bc) # using bc for >4GB
    if (( ${NUMBER_OF_GIGS} >= 1 )); then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Then once the need to split is determined, I know I need to call dd in a loop... but the problem is, what do I do about calculating seek points for dd if I can't use 64 bit integers in ksh conditional statements ?

I'm all confused !

Edit to clarify :  (1) I'm hoping to make a reasonably portable script, so preferably no GNU-only answers (2) No, split won't work for reasons outlined in my comment below ;-)

Comment: You're making things too complicated. How about using `split`? [And don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: see below comment to derobert..... split won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look up `split`; it may do what you want. (Also, as @Marco notes in his comment, don't parse `ls` output; consider using `stat -f '%s'` instead) If not:

You shouldn't need to calculate seek points, let the file descriptor do that for you. This is bash syntax:

```bash
for ((i = 0; i < n_blocks; ++i); do
    dd bs=4k count=262144
done < "input-file-name"
```

The key point being leave the input file open as `dd`'s stdin, then each time `dd` reads from it, it'll continue where it left off.

Comment: Re: Split..... no, that won't work. Due to the potential large file sizes, I can't have large copies of the file hanging around the disk... hence I'm looking to use dd to extract one or two blocks, process them, delete .... rinse and repeat...

Comment: @user119886 Sounds like you're looking for `split --filter` (if your split has that)

Comment: split filter.... sounds interesting, but looks GNU only, I was looking/hoping to make a reasonably portable script that would work on BSD too, and BSD split aint' got filter. ;-(

Comment: @user119886 the leave-the-fd-open approach with dd should be portable. Of course, `dd` is a whole can of worms itself.

Answer (score 0):

ATT ksh93, bash and dash (but not pdksh or mksh) and at least some BusyBox setups support 64-bit arithmetic even on 32-bit platforms.

You don't need 64-bit shell arithmetic as long as your files aren't larger than 4EB. Call `bc` once and for all to count the number of 1GB blocks in the file, then call `dd` once per block.

```
typeset size=$(ls -log -- "${1}" | awk 'NR==1 {print $3}')
typeset blocks=$(echo "($size - 1) / 1073741824" | bc)
typeset -i b
for ((b = 0; b < blocks; b++)); do
  dd if="$1" bs=1073741824 skip=$b | …
done
```

Alternatively, you can call `dd` in a loop, with the whole loop reading from the file. The difficulty is noticing when the input is empty; `dd` tells you on its standard error.

```
while
  case "$({ LC_ALL=C dd bs=1048576 count=1024 2>&3 | … 1>&4; } 3>&1)" in
    '0+0 records in'*) false;;
  esac
do
  :
done <"$1" 4>&1
```

If the file size is an exact multiple of the block size, the application is run with an empty file the last time. This seems difficult to avoid; a clumsy solution would be to read the next byte, though beware that if you read it into a shell variable you need to take care that if it's a null byte, you get an empty string.